# How to add static string to trusted ng-src?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I achieve the following?

```
<iframe ng-src="{{url | trusted}} + '?staticparam=test'"...>
```

Result:

```
Error: $interpolate:noconcat
Multiple Expressions
```

Comment: what is the value of `url` ??

Comment: Any  `http` url from the web, external.

Comment: Add '?staticparam=test' to your `url` in your controller.

Comment: Yes that might be an option, but I thought I could add in inside the html itself. So, no chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
<iframe ng-src="{{url  + '?staticparam=test' | trusted}}"...>
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-init might help appending :

```
<iframe ng-src="{{url | trusted}}" ng-init = "url = url + '?staticparam=test'">
```

Comment: Whenever the code runs down to the iframe, ng-init updates the scope of url..You wouldnt have to append the same in the controller if you need the updated url.

Comment: Oh no, it does not work: `Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{url + ?staticparam=test'}}] `